# How do you set previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation in Swift 2?

Tags: swift2, ios9, avcapturesession, uideviceorientation, ios9.1

In Objective-C you can do this:

```
if ( UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait( deviceOrientation ) || UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape( deviceOrientation ) ) {
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)self.previewView.layer;
    previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = (AVCaptureVideoOrientation)deviceOrientation;
}
```

But in Swift, what's the best way to translate this last line? You can't do "deviceOrientation as AVCaptureVideoOrientation".

Best I could come up with so far is:

```
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) || UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)) {
        let myPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = self.previewLayer
        myPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.init(rawValue: deviceOrientation.rawValue-1)!
    }
```

But this seems inelegant. The -1 is there because it's just an enum at the end of the day, and the UIDeviceOrientation enum has an "Unknown" one at position 0 that the AVCaptureVideoOrientation does not have...

Answer (score 1):

This does a great job on **swift 4**:

```
previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.rawValue)!
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let avLayer = (self.previewView.layer as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer)
let connection = avLayer.connection
let orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: self.interfaceOrientation.rawValue)!
connection.videoOrientation = orientation
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the conversion I got:

```
if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) || UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) {
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = previewView.layer
    previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = deviceOrientation
}
```

[The converter I used](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code) tends to not know what the code is supposed to look like some times (`Int` vs. `CGFloat`) so it might not work without de-bugging. let me know if it does what you want, for example, the variable could probably be changed to a constant.

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
```

You can find the constants AVCaptureVideoOrientation values in swift header files. (Swift 2)